# (403) Forbidden error - Office 365, CSOM for external users

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, csom, 2016

I use the below code

```
private static string userName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UserID"].ToString();
private static string password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Password"].ToString();
private static string siteUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SiteUrl"].ToString();
private static SharePointOnlineCredentials credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(userName, convertToSecureString(password));
var ctx = new ClientContext(siteUrl);
ctx.Credentials = credentials;
static SecureString convertToSecureString(string password)
        {
            SecureString encryptedPassword = new SecureString();
            foreach (var c in password.ToCharArray()) encryptedPassword.AppendChar(c);
            return encryptedPassword;
        }
```

Now this returns a 403 forbidden error

What else is missing here?

This worked in a different site collection that I tried

> Note: Difference in this site collection is that, the domain is
>   different. i.e if the client site is sss@client.com, I am logging in
>   using sss@mycompany.com, which is added as one of site collection
>   admin by the client i.e I am an external user for their site collection

Also I checked the response and found the below error

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this, looks like you are missing the authentication mode:

```
private static string userName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UserID"].ToString();
private static string password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Password"].ToString();
private static string siteUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SiteUrl"].ToString();

using (ClientContext context = new ClientContext(siteUrl))
{
    SecureString securePassword = new SecureString();
    foreach (char c in password.ToCharArray())
    {
        securePassword.AppendChar(c);
    }

    context.AuthenticationMode = ClientAuthenticationMode.Default;
    context.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(userName, securePassword);

    Web oWeb = context.Web;
    context.Load(oWeb, website => website.Title);
    context.ExecuteQuery();
}
```

Comment: tried adding it, no luck